# Poisson distribution: standard deviation of the difference

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation, poisson-distribution, differences

Two radioactive samples A and B are monitored. Let $X_A$ and $X_B$ be the number of events generated in the detector in time $t$.

When observed, A generates 100 events after a time $t$ ($x_A=100$) in the detector, B generates 81 events ($x_B=81)$.

The estimate of the standard deviation of $X_A$ is now

$\hat{\sigma}(X_A) = \sqrt{x_A} = 10$ and similarly

$\hat{\sigma}(X_B) = \sqrt{x_B} = 9$.

How can I estimate the standard deviation of the difference $X_A-X_B$?

Comment: There is no difference of A-B as the data is not paired. There is a difference of mean values. There are confidence intervals for A and for B, and standard errors for each.

Comment: You talk about A and B as *objects* (radioactive samples) not variables, so it doesn't make sense to talk about "sd(A)" nor even "sqrt(A)". "A" is not simultaneously the radioactive sample *and* the observed count (100), *and* a random variable (for which we could compute a standard deviation). Those are different things! I suggest you call the random variable (representing the number of counts that would be observed in observing the sample for a length of time $t$) $X_A$ (or maybe $N_A$) and the actual observed number $x_a$ (or $n_a$). In fact  I will clarify via an edit.

Comment: @Jonas I have edited to disambiguate the overloaded A and B by introducing symbols for the random variables and the values observed for them. You can still edit if you want to change it but I strongly suggest you avoid reintroducing the original confusion of distinct things.

Comment: What have you tried? e.g. did you consider whether you could compute the variance of the difference? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties